# Technical Analysis negative index

Tags: python, numpy, finance

I'm writting technical indicators with Python via Numpy. Say, for convenience one has an np.array called Price filled with Stock-Prices and wants to calculate some example indicator like:

```
for i in range (0,len(Price)):
    Indicator[i]=2*Price[i]+3*Price[i-1]+ .... + 34*Price[i-10]
```

Up to now I would separately calculate the first 10 entries of Indicator since `Price[-9]=Price[len(Price)-9]` and start the for loop at 10. Is there a way to simplify this, e.g. automatically omit values with negative indices like Price[-5]?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can write your transformation in terms [`numpy.convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html). For example, if

```
>>> price
array([-1,  4,  5,  0, -5,  2, -4,  4, 20,  1])
>>> coef
array([10, -2,  1])
```

(where, just for simplicity, I am using only 3 elements instead of 10), then

```
coef[0] * price[t] + coef[1] * price[t-1] + coef[2] * price[t-2]
```

is what `np.convolve` calculates, and *it also takes care of initial part of the series where we do not have 3 elements*:

```
>>> np.convolve(coef, price)
array([-10,  42,  41,  -6, -45,  30, -49,  50, 188, -26,  18,   1])
```

as you see, for the 1st element `-10 = 10 * -1`, for the 2nd element: `42 = 10 * 4 + -2 * -1`, and for, say, the 7th element: `-49 = 10 * -4 + -2 * 2 + 1 * -5`.